# Datatables Server side renders too many pages for pagination

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I am using the Datatables.net plugin and made my own server side script to return the json data, the json code looks like this.

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 100,
  "filteredTotal": 100,
  "data": [
    [
      "10",
      "2",
      "Dignissimos voluptatem odit commodi tenetur eaque ut. Reprehenderit asperiores accusamus ut enim rem fugiat suscipit. Beatae illo ipsum et non commodi. Sed consequuntur assumenda optio dignissimos.",
      "Occaecati ut pariatur optio maiores delectus ipsum rerum ipsam. Porro est dolores consequatur amet fugit cumque.",
      "9",
      "4",
      "3",
      "Repellat qui aliquam qui nostrum illum soluta debitis sint. Qui ut autem ut qui sint dolorum. Laborum neque ipsam eum non ut. Vel et expedita qui aut tempora qui."
    ],
    [
      "11",
      "4",
      "Pariatur rerum dolorem in quibusdam. Sunt iusto impedit perspiciatis et rerum possimus. Magni mollitia eos architecto. Laborum voluptatem mollitia dolorem porro.",
      "Doloribus vel aut quia ea et non consequuntur eligendi. Aut vero accusamus ipsa tenetur ullam perspiciatis. Exercitationem est facilis animi. Et alias modi dignissimos repudiandae.",
      "0",
      "2",
      "9",
      "Dolorem ullam ut illo est officia. Nesciunt nisi porro aut. Unde non pariatur ab aut. Enim quis ratione et ipsum voluptatem placeat."
    ],
    [
      "12",
      "2",
      "Consequatur dignissimos consequuntur repellendus enim quod. Aut ipsa cum enim perferendis. Qui et odit voluptatem ex quia temporibus quod. Culpa suscipit qui molestiae est labore.",
      "Quis sit quis et et harum ipsum accusantium. Quisquam aut fugiat ipsum ut velit autem cupiditate. Consequatur aut et voluptates totam porro et.",
      "0",
      "4",
      "6",
      "Dicta aut hic quia deleniti soluta soluta. Neque accusantium beatae ut et autem quo. Consequatur placeat vel dolores magnam alias dolorem. In nam et aspernatur esse ea reiciendis."
    ],
    [
      "13",
      "9",
      "Qui sit aut repellat consequatur quia reprehenderit non. Repellat quia quaerat aspernatur consequatur dolorum temporibus maxime illo. Recusandae optio explicabo saepe cupiditate.",
      "Nihil quae est suscipit ullam sed tempora nesciunt voluptates. Dolorum numquam temporibus est praesentium atque non cum. Quo veniam voluptatem repudiandae voluptas corrupti ipsa.",
      "1",
      "6",
      "1",
      "Harum officia iusto eveniet qui et. Dolores veritatis et error nam possimus nemo. Non natus sunt laborum magnam. Eum rerum laboriosam in eligendi nihil dolores recusandae distinctio."
    ],
    [
      "14",
      "2",
      "Sed veritatis et illum odio. Eius recusandae cumque qui animi quia enim. Unde repellendus ut sequi. Ea fugiat quasi ut in aut.",
      "Rerum nam deleniti voluptates quod fugit. Est exercitationem repellendus voluptates id. Minima dicta modi maxime.",
      "8",
      "0",
      "1",
      "Magnam et fugit tempore qui praesentium. Quia sit eum quo et quo aut. Iusto non sequi ducimus sint qui."
    ]
  ]
}
```

My request looks like this.

```
draw=1&columns[0][data]=0&columns[0][name]=p.id&columns[0][searchable]=false&columns[0][orderable]=false&columns[0][search][value]=&columns[0][search][regex]=false&columns[1][data]=1&columns[1][name]=p.supplier_id&columns[1][searchable]=false&columns[1][orderable]=false&columns[1][search][value]=&columns[1][search][regex]=false&columns[2][data]=2&columns[2][name]=p.title&columns[2][searchable]=false&columns[2][orderable]=false&columns[2][search][value]=&columns[2][search][regex]=false&columns[3][data]=3&columns[3][name]=p.permalink&columns[3][searchable]=false&columns[3][orderable]=false&columns[3][search][value]=&columns[3][search][regex]=false&columns[4][data]=4&columns[4][name]=p.mpn&columns[4][searchable]=false&columns[4][orderable]=false&columns[4][search][value]=&columns[4][search][regex]=false&columns[5][data]=5&columns[5][name]=p.barcode&columns[5][searchable]=false&columns[5][orderable]=false&columns[5][search][value]=&columns[5][search][regex]=false&columns[6][data]=6&columns[6][name]=p.spc&columns[6][searchable]=false&columns[6][orderable]=false&columns[6][search][value]=&columns[6][search][regex]=false&columns[7][data]=7&columns[7][name]=p.description&columns[7][searchable]=false&columns[7][orderable]=false&columns[7][search][value]=&columns[7][search][regex]=false&start=0&length=5&search[value]=&search[regex]=false&_=1475131244317
```

Then I use pagination on my datatables but I should expect 20 pages with 5 records making it a total of 100 when I try it the pagination is working but it generates too many pages it goes on endlessly.

[image: datatables too many pages]

This is the javascript where I initialize the datatable.

```
<script>
$('#products').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "/product/data",
        "searching": false,
        "ordering": false,
        "columns": [
            { name: 'p.id', "searchable": true },
            { name: 'p.supplier_id', "searchable": false },
            { name: 'p.title', "searchable": false },
            { name: 'p.permalink', "searchable": false },
            { name: 'p.mpn', "searchable": false },
            { name: 'p.barcode', "searchable": false },
            { name: 'p.spc', "searchable": false },
            { name: 'p.description', "searchable": false }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution the key `filteredTotal` in the return JSON has to be `recordsFiltered`. After I changed this my pagination worked normally.